# Visual studio: How to open visual studio in current folder from cmd line

Tags: visual-studio, dotnet-cli

Does anyone know how to open Visual studio from the command line from the current 
working directory. 
 I know that when using **VS code** this is very simple. You just type `code .` and it works. 
Here, I'm searching for the **Visual studio equivalent**.

Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 4):

Found it:

```
devenv ./mysolutionname.sln
```

To get this to work, you need to make sure that devenv is contained in your **PATH** variable. 
Also you need to run this cmd **as an administrator**. You can open a window from your file explorer in your current folder as an administrator, by typing ALT-F and then use arrow button||letters to navigate. Press Enter on cmd|powershell as administrator.

[image]

Tip: If you start from an empty folder, you can use **dotnet-cli** to create a empty sln file

```
dotnet new sln mysolutionname
```

Also you can create a new project and add it to the solution using the dotnet-cli

```
dotnet new console -n myprojectname
dotnet sln add myprojectname
```

Comment: I would just add that you should use "devenv *.sln" then tab to solve the regex. Useful when you work with many different solutions :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/devenv-command-line-switches?view=vs-2019) there's no such switch. There is no way to set the curent working directory. But you *can* open an existing solution.